# How to deal with different encodings across multiple web browsers

Tags: c#, browser, encoding

I have a website which contains french, with accents "é, è, à,...".

The website displays fine in chrome but those symbols are messed up in firefox. I generated these pages with C# StreamWriter. I choose Encoding "UTF8".

I've tried with ISO-8859-1 and ASCII too with little succes.

Is there a way to figure out which encoding I can use that will display fine in every browser?

EDIT *

Ok here is a sum of what I've did

I read the file with Default encoding
I write it back to the drive with a StreamWriter

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
```

In every single page there is a meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Both of my browsers are set to Encoding -> ISO-8859-1

I still get errors in Firefox and Chrome displays fine.

If you want to see the page its

http://www.amrikart.com/centretechno.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the Content-Type header (or the equivalent meta tag) to the encoding you used to generate the document, so the browser can reliably decode your content. Here is an [article explaining the details](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset). For international characters, a good choice of encoding is UTF-8.

If you don't feel you understand why this is necessary, or what the character encoding is; [go read this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).